# How to call a function when a single key is pressed with pure javascript on the whole page

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I'm trying to write a user script which would offer html editing via`contenteditable`and save the result locally...

I would like to activate it when a single key is pressed *(like **§** as example)* everywhere on the page *(making an Entire Page Editable)*.

Currently, I [tried a minimal subset](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/native-rich-text-editing-with-the-contenteditable-attribute) where the function is called by ctrl+s :

```
$("body").keydown(function (event) {
    // Only Ctrl-S and Command-S (19)
    if (!(String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 's' && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19))
    return true;

    document.location = 'data:text/attachment;,' + document.documentElement.innerHTML;

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

but nothing append unusually... and opera dragonfly didn't show any exceptions *(the script is loaded in the debugger)*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("keydown",doKeyDown,false);

function doKeyDown(e) {
   switch(§.keyCode) {
        case 167:
       document.location = 'data:text/attachment;,' + document.documentElement.innerHTML;
       break;
   }

}


</script>
```

Comment: in this case 87 is the w key. I couldn't find the key code for §.

Comment: 0 `function doKeyDown(e) {
   console.log(e.keyCode);
}`

Answer (score 0):

To make the document editable, you can use:

```
document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('contenteditable', '');
```

This is the equivalent of specifying:

```
<html contenteditable>
```

Setting `document.location` to the document's `innerHTML` property will break any JavaScript bound to events on the page.

Here is a complete version that works for me in Chrome.

```
var isEditable = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
{
  if (isEditable)
    return;

  if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() == 's' && e.ctrlKey)
  {
    document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('contenteditable', '');
    isEditable = true;
  }
}, false);
```

To learn more about the keyboard events, try this code in the JavaScript console:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { console.dir(e); }, false);
```

Comment: the purpose of `document.location = 'data:text/attachment;,' + document.documentElement.innerHTML;`is to save the edited version of the html file.

Comment: So what about your code isn't working exactly? Is setting the location failing, or is your keystroke not being handled?

Comment: I have no idea... As nothing is happening. I just want to say you are wrong in your answer by writing `document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('contenteditable', '');` inside the`if`statement. Your function work correctly, but that's not the reason I want to use a special keystroke.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your browser's debugger? Have you tried the suggestion I made at the end of my answer?

Comment: `document.location = 'data:text/attachment;,' + document.documentElement.innerHTML;`work near correctly.